# Mysql: return 0 when result 1 row in a table, other table result is 2 rows

Tags: mysql

How to display result

```
Temp | Order | Payment
A | 5 | 3
A | 4 | 0
B | 2 | 2
B | 0 | 3
C | 3 | 0
```

with: first_table:

```
Name | Description
A | Description A
B | Description B
C | Description C
```

second_table:

```
Name | order
A | 5
A | 4
B | 2
C | 3
```

third_table:

```
Name | Payment
A | 3
B | 2
B | 3
```

Meaning:
there are 2 order (value: 4,5) with Name=A.
there is 1 order (value: 3) with Name = A
And result I want to display:

```
Name | Order | Payment
A | 4 | 3 |
A | 5 | 0 |
```

Any help me?

Comment: what's your efforts so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

From your example there is no Payment for order A5 so you should use LEFT JOIN which will result in Payment being NULL for that row (A5). LEFT JOIN basically means "select rows from first table and if there is no match in second table, put NULL".

Simply do a LEFT JOIN on second_table and third_table on field Name where Name=a. It's a very basic example so I won't give you the exact query, you should learn it by yourself.